# OSX resource allocation?

Tags: cpu-usage, osx-mavericks, ram, video-conversion

I am in the process of converting all .avi files to .mp4 (for compatibility with my PS3 and iPad).

I noticed today that both the applications I've used so far (MPEG Streamclip & Handbrake) only use around 30% of my CPU and only about 300Mb of my available RAM (4GB installed). Why is this? Is there  any way to speed this conversations up by somehow allowing the applications to use more of the available resources?

I am currently running Mavericks on an MBP with a 2.4GHz i5, 4GB RAM, 256MB NVIDIA GeForce GT330M and a hybrid drive so I don't know where, if any, bottle necks would be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow is a place to discuss coding, programming and software development.

Head over to http://www.superuser.com/, and ask there. They're the people you want to talk to about this.

Good luck!

Comment: No worries at all. If you could tag my answer as the correct one, I would appreciate it!

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes to accept an answer sadly but I will accept it after that!

Comment: Cheers mate. Good luck with your issue at SuperUser!